# TFS Build: How to get EXE file deployed to website

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS Build Definition that builds/deploys a web project to our internal IIS server.  That works fine.  However, I would also like to build/deploy a WinForms app (.exe) to the same web site.

I did add the WinForms solution to the Build Definition.  TFS builds the .exe and copies it to the drops folder.  But it's not in the _PublishedWebsites folder.

I've been manually copying the file over to the web site.  Is there a way to automate this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TFS 2013 has support for post build powershell scripts, it could probably be done as part of an MSBuild task too.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML build, you can check in your script, and specify a post-build script path in your XAML build definition. [This](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1) script gathers some of the typical binary types from the typical locations and copies them to the folder from which TFBuild copies and drops to your staging location. Check more information about Run a script in your XAML build process at website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn376353%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

If you upgrade to TFS 2015, in the new build system, you can simply add a PublishBuildArtifacts task in your build definition. About how to use this task, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I've discovered that I do not have options to run pre/post scripts because my build definition was originally configured from DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml.  Is it possible to add pre/post script options to v11 templates?  Or must I jump to v12?  I tried to edit my v11 build definition using a text editor, but it seems v11 and v12 are syntactically different.  I'd rather not switch to a v12 template because my v11 based template has been highly customized over the years.  I just want the ability to add pre/post scripts to what I already am using.  Thanks!

Comment: You can add an InvokeProcess activity in your workflow to call a bat file which has a xcopy in it.